# Using 'continue' with boolean-based statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean-logic

**For those of you who didn't understand - I KNOW this is NOT how a good code should look like... The purpose of this tricky question is to write a code without if-statements in order to practice boolean logic...**

I'm trying to solve a question in C which restricts the programmer from using if/else/switch statements. **cant use ternary operators either.**
The idea is to use boolean based logical statements to get the "wanted path".
i.e - instead of:

```
if (1 > 0)
   printf("TRUE")
else
   printf("FALSE")
```

I would use:

```
bool res = true;
res = (1 > 0 && printf("TRUE")) || printf("FALSE")
```

(this is the general idea, using the boolean statement processing logic to manipulate different actions.
The only problem I ran into was to replace a part that looks somewhat like this (where i want the program to skip a certain part of the loop if A is equal to B):

```
while (...)
{
   if (A == B)
       continue;
   //code
}
```

Do you know if this is possible to execute without using if/else/switch statements?

Thanks!!

Comment: I didn't understand it completely but it seems yor're looking for ternary operators https://guide.freecodecamp.org/c/ternary-operator/

Comment: any rationale against `if`.

Comment: a!=b && function() <- with the //code?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Might work! the only problem is that the original while loop has some lines that cannot be executed within a function that will be called every time the while loop resets. (counters, sum and another parameters that greatly rely on the while loop conditions)

Comment: In my undergrad studies (many years ago), I recall hearing a lecture that explain that ALL control flow commands (if, for, while, do {} while, switch), with the exception of goto, can be implemented using the while. I wish I can find the reference/proof for that. This was part of a lecture about code verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent of your

```
while (condition)
{
   foo();
   if (A == B)
       continue;
   bar();
   baz();
}
```

is

```
while (condition)
{
   foo();
   (A != B) && bar();
   (A != B) && baz();
}
```

This assumes `bar()` doesn't change `A` or `B`. If it does, use a temporary variable:

```
while (condition)
{
   foo();
   bool cond = A != B;
   cond && bar();
   cond && baz();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know if this is possible to execute without using if/else/switch statements?

With gcc extension [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) you can do this:

```
int main() {
    int A, B;
    while (1) {
        A == B && ({continue;0;});
    }
}
```

Please don't do this and please don't do `res = (1 > 0 && printf("TRUE")) || printf("FALSE")`. Just write `if`s.

Comment: Is that standard C syntax? im using c99 and this does not compile

Comment: No, it's not, it's a gcc extension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming OK to use `state` variable then

```
while (...)
{
   if (A == B)
       continue;
   //code
}
```

Can be implemented as

```
state = true ;
while ( ... ) {
   ...
   while ( a == b ) {
       state = false ;
       break ;
   } ;
   while ( !state ) {
       // code here
       break ;
   } ;
}
```

Or with fewer clutter, if allowed:

```
while (...)
{
   state = A == B ;
   while ( state ) {
       //code here
       break ;
   } ;
}
```

With relatively minor performance penalty from having to double-test.

Side note: In my undergrad studies (many years ago), I recall hearing a lecture that explain that ALL control flow commands (if, while, do {} while, switch, with the exception of goto), can be implemented using the `while`. I wish I can find the reference/proof for that. This was part of a lecture about code verification.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> if (1 > 0)
>    printf("TRUE")
> else
>    printf("FALSE")
> ```
>
> I would use:
>
> ```
> bool res = true;
> res = (1 > 0 && printf("TRUE")) || printf("FALSE")
> ```

If I see such a code written by any programmer in my team I would fire him/her.

Why? Your version is not human readable, it is error prone and almost not debugable.

Comment: He asked for a boolean based expression solution and not for "how I can do it on my next team based coding job".